# Delete the contents of the cell in case of type-mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

An examined column may contain incorrect dates.
For example: 2022.04-05 (April-May) or text, so in case of `CDate` I get type-mismatch error.

Is there any possibility to delete cells in case of type-mismatch error without interrupting the macro?
I mean if `CDate` is not possible, delete the contents of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`IsDate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function):

> Returns **True** if the expression is a date or is recognizable as a valid date or time; otherwise, it returns **False**.

```
If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
   ' collect how many are older than 1 year
Else
   cell.ClearContents
End If
```